# How to run additional statements in eclipse(pdt for PHP)?

Tags: eclipse, debugging

Like firebug's console,I can type in the scripts directly.

Is there a similar place in eclipse out there?

Or do I install some plugin to have the feature?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Display window to type in code snippets, set variable values and evaluate whilst debugging.

http://help.eclipse.org/help32/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/views/display/ref-display_view.htm

Comment: Seems it's diabled in **eclipse pdt** (for `php`)?

Answer (score 0):

The "watch" view can be used to execute simple snippets of code.

In some circumstances, I use the groovy shell (in a separate window) to check how a code snippet will behave. It isn't practical when complex data structures or library classes are involved, but for a respectable number of cases it works very well.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Expression and Display views. There's a set of excellent free video tutorials on the Eclipse debugger that you can [see here](http://eclipsetutorial.sourceforge.net/debugger.html). The aforementioned views are talked about in lesson 3.